# Views 3 "Use aggregation true" with exposed filter

Tags: views, css-js-aggregation

I have a searching page and I need to show the results separated by there bundle type (all are nodes)  and I need to show how many results(In total) received for each content type .
I created a view the shows the main results and attached views for each separated content type then I made another attached view (inherit the filter from the main view) and then choose node type in the fields twice one I selected the count option from  the aggregation config .
when there is no expose filter and default is for show all I received in the attached view the correct results (shows all the content types with the number of Occurrences) but when I enter a word in the exposed filter it shows me the correct results but its not aggregate them